# Getting error builder.knex(...).queryBuilder is not a function

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sails.js, knex.js, objection.js

When running the app with `sails lift` it all works fine and as expected, but when I run this in the Jest test suite, it stops working.

In another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740398/objection-js-query-builder-not-a-function-using-insert-method) it is mentioned that this means the Knex config wasn't given to Objection correctly, but there's no discrepancy between Knex using Jest and the running production code.

The BeforeAll() function

```
async function createMockUsers() {
  config.users.forEach(async function(user) {
    await sails.helpers.createUser(
      user.firstName,
      user.lastName,
      user.phone,
      user.password,
      user.role
    );
  });
}

// Before running any tests...
beforeAll(function(done) {
  // process.env = config.env_variables;

  sails.lift({

    // Your sails app's configuration files will be loaded automatically,
    // but you can also specify any other special overrides here for testing purposes.

    // For example, we might want to skip the Grunt hook,
    // and disable all logs except errors and warnings:
    // hooks: { grunt: false },
    log: { level: 'warn' },
    port: 1338,

  }, async function(err) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    await createMockUsers();
    // here you can load fixtures, etc.


    return done();
  });
}, 60000);
```

The Error

```
TypeError: builder.knex(...).queryBuilder is not a function
    at buildKnexQuery (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\objection\lib\queryBuilder\QueryBuilder.js:1359:63)
    at doExecute (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\objection\lib\queryBuilder\QueryBuilder.js:1250:31)
    at Bluebird.try.then (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\objection\lib\queryBuilder\QueryBuilder.js:563:19)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async.Object.<anonymous>.Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Binny Zupnick\Development\onefiftyone\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
```

The Model

```
let Knex  = require('knex');
const knexfile = require('../../knexfile');
const { Model } = require('objection');

// Give the knex object to objection.
const knexConfig = Knex(knexfile['connection']);
Model.knex(knexConfig);


class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'user';
  }
}

module.exports = {
  User: User
};
```

Knexfile

```
// Update with your config settings.

function getSsl() {
  return process.env.PG_SSL !== "false";
}

function connectionStringToObject(connectionString) {
  let connectionObject = {};
  let noPostgres = connectionString.split('//')[1];
  let splitByColon = noPostgres.split(':');
  let splitByStrudel = splitByColon[1].split('@');
  let splitBySlash = splitByColon[2].split('/');

  connectionObject['user'] = splitByColon[0];
  connectionObject['host'] = splitByStrudel[1];
  connectionObject['password'] = splitByStrudel[0];
  connectionObject['database'] = splitBySlash[1];
  connectionObject['ssl'] = getSsl();

  return connectionObject;
}

let connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
let connectionObject = connectionStringToObject(connectionString);

let dbConnection = {
    client : "pg",
  connection: connectionObject,
  migrations: {
    directory: './db/migrations'
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true
};

module.exports = {
  connection: dbConnection
};
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I also get this error now and my file contents look similar. Thanks